# Why do I get warnings when using Spring HATEOAS Jackson serializers

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jackson, spring-hateoas

Spring HATEOAS [defines](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hateoas/blob/050eae06d330538ade185f740cc4145876a294f3/src/main/java/org/springframework/hateoas/hal/Jackson2HalModule.java) and [registers](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hateoas/blob/050eae06d330538ade185f740cc4145876a294f3/src/main/java/org/springframework/hateoas/config/HypermediaSupportBeanDefinitionRegistrar.java#L262-L288) a `HttpMessageConverter` with a Jackson module that contains serializers to transform its `ResourceSupport` and `Resources` types to HAL JSON representations. The modules uses [Jackson mixins](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hateoas/blob/050eae06d330538ade185f740cc4145876a294f3/src/main/java/org/springframework/hateoas/hal/Jackson2HalModule.java#L86-L88) to bind the serializers to types like so:

```
package org.springframework.hateoas.hal;

// Imports omitted

public abstract class ResourcesMixin<T> extends Resources<T> {

    @Override
    @XmlElement(name = "embedded")
    @JsonProperty("_embedded")
    @JsonSerialize(include = JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_EMPTY, using = Jackson2HalModule.HalResourcesSerializer.class)
    @JsonDeserialize(using = Jackson2HalModule.HalResourcesDeserializer.class)
    public abstract Collection<T> getContent();    
}
```

This mixin causes types that extend `Resources<T>` to get serialized and deserialized using `Jackson2HalModule.HalResourcesSerializer.class`. However, the implementation [seems limited in its ability to embed resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25858698/spring-hateoas-embedded-resource-support). In trying to address this limitation, **I tried using annotations from the above Jackson mixin to use the Spring HATEOAS serializers in my own class**:

```
package mypackage;

// Imports omitted

public class ModelAResource extends Resource<ModelA> {

    private Collection<Resource<ModelB>> modelBResources;

    public ModelAResource(Model model, Collection<Resource<ModelB>> modelBResources) {
        super(model);
        this.modelBResources = modelBResources;
    }

    @JsonProperty("_embedded")
    @JsonSerialize(include = JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_EMPTY, using = Jackson2HalModule.HalResourcesSerializer.class)
    @JsonDeserialize(using = Jackson2HalModule.HalResourcesDeserializer.class)
    public Collection<Resource<ModelB>> getModelBResources() {
        return modelBResources;
    }
}
```

**This works, but leads to the following `WARN`s getting logged**:

```
[2015-01-27 23:36:41.469] boot - 12516  WARN [qtp1175418534-17] ---
MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter: Failed to evaluate serialization for type
[class mypackage.ModelAResource]:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean 
with name
'org.springframework.hateoas.hal.Jackson2HalModule$HalResourcesSerializer':
Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate
[org.springframework.hateoas.hal.Jackson2HalModule$HalResourcesSerializer]: No
default constructor found; nested exception is
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:
org.springframework.hateoas.hal.Jackson2HalModule$HalResourcesSerializer<init>()

[2015-01-27 23:36:41.478] boot - 12516  WARN [qtp1175418534-17] ---
MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter: Failed to evaluate serialization for type
[class mypackage.ModelAResource]:
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Class
org.springframework.hateoas.hal.Jackson2HalModule$HalResourcesSerializer has no 
default (no arg) constructor
```

Despite these warnings, serialization yields the expected, desired result:

```
{
  "id" : 6,
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/modelA/6"
    },
    "links" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/modelA/6/modelBs"
    }
  },
  "_embedded" : {
    "modelBs" : [ {
      "_links": {
        "self": {
          "href": "http://localhost:8080/modelA/6/modelBs/1"
        }
      }, 
      "id" : 1
    } ]
  }
}
```

So why the warnings, and why does it work despite the warnings? The [module and serializer are public](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hateoas/blob/050eae06d330538ade185f740cc4145876a294f3/src/main/java/org/springframework/hateoas/hal/Jackson2HalModule.java#L237).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `@JsonDeserialize(using = Jackson2HalModule.HalResourcesDeserializer.class)`, then Jackson tries to create an instance of `Jackson2HalModule.HalResourcesSerializer`, which doesn't work because it has no default constructor.

Spring HATEOAS (later) **directly** registers some Jackson stuff, including a `Jackson2HalModule.HalResourcesSerializer`. Now serialization works as expected because an instance of the serializer has successfully been registered.