# Spring MVC & custom JsonSerializer

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

I'm using Spring 5.0 with MVC and have a custom (de)serializer for an entity, e.g.

```
@JsonDeSerialize(using = RoleDeserializer.class)
public class Role implements Serializable { 
....
```

and for deserializing I have (StdDesializer won't change anything)

```
public class RoleDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Role> {
  EntityManager em;
  public RoleDeserializer(EntityManager em) {
        this.em = em;
  }
....
```

which gives me always an Exception

```
MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter:205 Failed to evaluate Jackson deserialization for type [[simple type, class test.Role]]: c
om.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Class test.RoleDeserializer has no default (no arg) constructor
```

but somehow I need to have **that** constructor since if I do it like

```
public class RoleDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Role> {
@PersitenceContext
EntityManager em;
 ....
```

The automatic annotation on `em` with `@PersitenceContext` does not work because it is not injected with Spring, i.e. not initialized.

Remark: Following the [suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28393599/autowiring-in-jsondeserializer-springbeanautowiringsupport-vs-handlerinstantiat) I could not resolve the issue. The reason of the behavior is explained in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28182567/why-do-i-get-warnings-when-using-spring-hateoas-jackson-serializers) - but this does not get rid of the Exceptions :-/

Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check out this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/20551381/2143488

Comment: Thx for the hint - this gave me the leading hint how to resolve it - see below.

Comment: 0

I'm trying to achieve the same thing, injecting the entityManager in a JsonDeserializer class. I see your code references builder. What field is this, and what does it do? The code is unclear.

Comment: As far as I remember you need to approach it on a general level, i.e. following the answer gives you the possibility that these will be injected.

Answer (score 0):

After the hint to my question I figured out how to resolve this issue in Spring 5.0 (most likely as well in 4.1.1) - without XML:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {    
        final HashMap<Class<?>, JsonDeserializer<?>> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put(Role.class, new RoleDeserializer());
        // more classes could be easily attached the same way...
        builder.deserializersByType(map);

        converters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(builder.build()));
    }
}
```

after this the annotations `@Autowired` or `@PersistenceContext` work as expected in the classes :-)
Thx for the support!