# Lazy loading in custom Spring Data JPA + REST controller

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

Following some of the recommendations in [How to correctly use PagedResourcesAssembler from Spring Data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21346387/how-to-correctly-use-pagedresourcesassembler-from-spring-data) I've created a controller to handle some custom query requests for an entity. The classes look like:

```
@BasePathAwareController
public class FooController implements ResourceProcessor<RepositorySearchesResource> {

    @Autowired
    FooRepo repo;

    @RequestMapping("/foo/search/findFooByAttribute")
    public ResponseEntity<PagedResources<Resource<Foo>>> findByAttribute(
            PersistentEntityResourceAssembler entityAssembler) {

        Page<Foo> results = repo.findAll(
                Specifications.where(FooSpec.isOpen()),
                new PageRequest(1, 20));

        return new ResponseEntity<PagedResources<Resource<Foo>>>(
                resourceAssembler.toResource(results),
                HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @Override
    public RepositorySearchesResource process(
            RepositorySearchesResource resource) {
    ...
    }
}
```

where `FooRepo` is a repository interface annotated with `@RestResource`. If do a GET to `/foo` (the default findAll) the endpoint is able to retrieve a `@OneToMany` collection mapping on the Foo entity during the serialization process. But in my custom repository, I get the famous `could not initialize proxy - no Session` exception. How can I make my custom controller behave in the same way as the generated controller that `@RestResource` seems to create with regards to keeping the Hibernate session open?

Comment: Have you tried to annotate your controller with RepositoryRestController instead of BasePathAwareController

Comment: Instead of returning `ResponseEntity<PagedResources<Resource<T>>>`, have you tried returning `Resources<T>` by using `Resources.wrap()` to generate the resources from your entities? Also available for `PagedResources<T>`