# Spring Data REST: Multiple endpoints for one entity

Tags: spring-security, spring-data, spring-data-rest

**Premise:**
A web-service exposes its data via REST. Each record belongs to the user who created the record (row-level-security). Users may only retrieve own records.

```java
@RepositoryRestResource(path = "talks")
public interface TalkRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Talk, Long> {

    @Override
    @Query("select t from Talk t where t.owner.id= ?#{principal?.id}")
    Page<Talk> findAll(Pageable pageable);
}
```

That repository is now available under a `/talks` endpoint.

**Question:**
Is there a way 1) to expose the same domain entity at multiple endpoints and 2) define different `@Query` annotations depending on the endpoint?

- `/talks`
  I'd let that be my default implementation open to admin roles
- `/me/talks`
  this is the endpoint that applies row level security against the principal and as part of the `/me/**` endpoints is exposed as public api to implementing clients.

This question is partially related to https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-555, but only in so far that the additional path segment is currently not supported.

**Rationale:**
I like the idea of not having to put too much conditional logic into SPeL queries like `is owner or has_some_role` (some examples [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/blob/master/jpa/security/src/main/java/example/springdata/jpa/security/SecureBusinessObjectRepository.java)). Further it would become easy to protect the `/me/**` endpoints by different strategies than the default API (e.g. only `/me/**` might be subject to OAuth2).

Comment: Just write a controller, bind it to a URI and call the repository yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If you know better/more concise solutions I am happy to accept other answers.**

Based on the suggestion of @OliverGierke, the [official docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#customizing-sdr.overriding-sdr-response-handlers) and various other SO answers (also almost exclusively by Oliver, mostly [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31758862/enable-hal-serialization-in-spring-boot-for-custom-controller-method), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21346387/how-to-correctly-use-pagedresourcesassembler-from-spring-data) and [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16790371/spring-mvc-3-return-a-spring-data-page-as-json/16794740#16794740)) I have implemented a custom controller to serve the endpoint.

This also enables projections on the custom endpoint and uses Spring Data REST's HATEOS assembler to provide the `HAL+JSON` output. What I haven't worked on so far is how to reuse the profile and alps logic that SDR provides out of the box but gets lost within the custom controller.

```java
@BasePathAwareController
public class MyTalksController {

    private final TalkRepository repository;
    private final PagedResourcesAssembler pagedResourcesAssembler;

    @Autowired
    public MyTalksController(TalkRepository repo, PagedResourcesAssembler assembler) {
        repository = repo;
        pagedResourcesAssembler = assembler;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/me/talks")
    @ResponseBody
    public PagedResources<?> getTalks(Pageable pageable, PersistentEntityResourceAssembler entityAssembler) {
        Page<Talk> talks = repository.meFindAll(pageable);
        return pagedResourcesAssembler.toResource(talks, entityAssembler);
    }
}
```

Comment: do you know if something is possible without using PagedResourceAssembler?

Answer (score 0):

Answering 1) — yes, possible as follows:

```
// skipping old requests for the sake of the backward compatibility with the clients
// just returning ok with HTTP status 200
@RequestMapping(method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.OPTIONS, RequestMethod.DELETE},
                value = {"/lock", "/configure", "/cancel", "/initialize", "/register"})
public ApiResponse ok() {
    return ApiResponse.success();
}
```

Answering 2) — different query logic will naturally fit different endpoints, so there is a need to create a corresponding method for each one, I'd assume.