# Spring MVC - Data Page formatted as JSON, getting error: unable to infer type arguments for ResponseEntity<>

Tags: json, spring, arguments, spring-hateoas, httpentity

I am following the first answer to this question : 
[Spring MVC 3: return a Spring-Data Page as JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16790371/spring-mvc-3-return-a-spring-data-page-as-json)

I am getting compilation error `Cannot infer type arguments for ResponseEntity<>` in the following block of code :

```
@GetMapping("all")
@RequestMapping(produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
public HttpEntity<PagedResources<SearchDto>> get(@PageableDefault Pageable p, PagedResourcesAssembler<SearchDto> assembler) {
    Page<SearchDto> results = searchService.findAll(p);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(assembler.toResource(results), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

When I first tried to use this code, I was missing dependencies, so I added:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.hateoas</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-hateoas</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I am using a snapshot, so I didn't include a version.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
```

I attempted to change the problem line to :

```
return new ResponseEntity<PagedResources<SearchDto>>(assembler.toResource(results), HttpStatus.OK);
```

but instead get the error `The constructor ResponseEntity<PagedResources<SearchDto>>(PagedResources<Resource<SearchDto>>, HttpStatus) is undefined`. This comes with the suggestions:

1. `Remove arguments to match ResponseEntity<PagedResources<SearchDto>>( HttpStatus)` This would not return my search results at all.
2. `Cast argument 1 into MultiValueMap<String,String>`. I looked through the parent classes of PagedResources, and it wouldn't be able to cast to a MultiValueMap. Also, it would be a problem if my numbers came in as strings in the JSON.

So I would like to be able to return a JSON with page metadata and the result set.  Thank you for reading.